# Grails executor plugin callAsync block always taking the same values

Tags: grails, threadpool, java.util.concurrent, executor

I'm trying to use the executor plugin in grails but I'm having a problem which I am not able to solve.
Basically, i have a list of links that I want to crawl and I was having an issue where it was always crawling the same ones, so I simplified my example to this:

```
    List offerLinks = getOfferLinks(parser)
    offerLinks.each{println it}

    List futures = new Vector()
    for (def link : offerLinks) {
        def future = callAsync {
            return link
        }
        futures.add(future)
    }

    futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}
```

This is what gets printed in the console

bt-ofrd-acciona-6633344.htm?
bt-ofrd-celiasiffredi-293068.htm?
bt-ofrd-clahubiz-92924.htm?
bt-ofrd-haruko-1672632.htm?
FUTURE bt-ofrd-clahubiz-92924.htm?
FUTURE bt-ofrd-haruko-1672632.htm?
FUTURE bt-ofrd-haruko-1672632.htm?
FUTURE bt-ofrd-haruko-1672632.htm?

The first 4 results are for the `offerLinks.each{println it}` code
The last 4 are for `futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}`

What I'm trying to find out is why putting those links in the callAsync block and retrieving them from the future objects make them take the last value, it seems like its replacing the already created future objects?

This piece of code is inside a service called by a controller.
I appreciate any help you can give me. Thanks

**Update**:
I'm thinking there is some kind of problem in the Java executor API... or maybe I'm don't fully understand how it really works?
Here is another test changing the code to use invokeAll:

```
    def threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

    List offerLinks = getOfferLinks(parser)
    List lista = new ArrayList()
    for (enlace in offerLinks) {
        println "link " + enlace
        lista.add({enlace} as Callable)
    }
    def futures = threadPool.invokeAll(lista)

    futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}
```

This is what gets printed
link /bt-ofrd-implementar-192996.htm?
link /bt-ofrd-cdonini-864908.htm?
link /bt-ofrd-hvtalent-1493932.htm?
link /bt-ofrd-dbak-1358120.htm?
link /bt-ofrd-hexacta-100072.htm?
link /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?
FUTURE /bt-ofrd-ccibelli-457472.htm?

Comment: I've posted a possible workaround, but the most obvious question to ask is what exactly is `offerLinks` a `List` _of_?  If they're normal `String` objects then what you have so far should work correctly, but if they're some sort of mutable object (where the iterator gives you the same object reference each time but with mutated internal data) then you'll have to do something else like capture the `toString` value within your `for` loop and pass that into the closure instead of the original object.

Comment: yes, offerLinks is a list of Strings. I also tried with this code modifications: `List offerLinks = ["1","2","3"]` and `lista.add({enlace.toString()} as Callable)`. Both return the same result (the last value is repeated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like something odd is going on with the scope of variables defined outside the closure but referred to from inside, it's not "closing" properly.  Does it work any better if you do

```
def threadPool = Executors.newCachedThreadPool()

List offerLinks = getOfferLinks(parser)
List lista = new ArrayList()
for (enlace in offerLinks) {
    println "link " + enlace
    lista.add(({ it }.curry(enlace)) as Callable)
}
def futures = threadPool.invokeAll(lista)

futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}
```

This should ensure that the right thing gets passed into the closure, and the closure itself doesn't need to refer to the externally-defined `enlace` variable directly.

This doesn't on its own explain *why* what you've already tried didn't work, but it might give you a workaround.

---

Edit: I didn't spot this before, but I now notice that you aren't *declaring* `enlace` in that `for` loop, so it's not a local variable and the closures are (correctly) referring to a single shared variable rather than "closing" over the value in a particular loop iteration.  It should work if you use a construction like this instead:

```
def tasks = offerLinks.collect { link ->
  println "link " + enlace
  return ({ link } as Callable)
}
def futures = threadPool.invokeAll(tasks)
futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}
```

where the `link` variable is local to the `collect` closure, so the `{...} as Callable` will close over the correct value.  The equivalent in terms of `callAsync` would be to use

```
List futures = offerLinks.collect { link ->
  callAsync { link }
}
```

Comment: This works with the modified code. I will change back to the test the callAsync and update to tell you what happens. Thank you very much!

Comment: @gabrieeel I've spotted another possibility, take a look at my edit and see if that helps.

Comment: Isn't this code `for (enlace in offerLinks) {` declaring an enlace variable in the for loop? I also tried `for (def enlace : offerLinks)` with the same results. Anyhow, I tried both of your latest solutions and they work like a charm. Thanks a lot, Ian!

Answer (score 0):

Is this better?

```
List offerLinks = getOfferLinks(parser)
offerLinks.each{println it}

List futures = new Vector()
for (def link : offerLinks) {
    futures.add( callAsync {
        return link
    }
```

)
    }

```
futures.each{println "FUTURE " +  it.get()}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the same phenonemon I just experienced, see [this answer](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Log4j-MDC-problem-with-runAsync-td4641782.html).

For me, the problem was that "The current thread's MDC is inherited by newly spawned threads". I don't know the why of that, so I can't tell why you may bump into the same problem - but maybe because you retrieve the links from a service?